# Prevent simultaneous audio playback from 2 different players (WordPress plugin)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, audio, plugins, audio-player

I recently bought and installed [Plate III](http://codecanyon.net/item/plate-iii-music-streaming-plugin-for-wordpress/11552808) an audio player plugin for a WordPress site.

I installed two players on the same page.

When I start a song on Player #1 and then start another song on Player #2, the first song doesn't stop and there is simultaneous playback.

I contacted the author without any response yet and tried and make some research here for a way to prevent this but couldn't find it...

In a javascript file (plate.js) there is a function that says :

```js
.on('start.plateEvents', function(e, track) {
    $this.find('.control .pause').show();
    $this.find('.control .stop').show();
    $this.find('.control .play').hide();
  })
  .on('pause.plateEvents', function(e, track) {
    $this.find('.control .pause').hide();
    $this.find('.control .stop').hide();
    $this.find('.control .play').show();
  })
  .on('stop.plateEvents', function(e, track) {
    $this.find('.curTime').html(player.uiTime(0));
    $this.find('.allTime').html(player.uiTime(Infinity));
    $this.find('.progress').val(0).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  })
```

I am thinking that if I could add somewhere in the .on('start.plateEvents')... an instruction to stop the track  that is playing from the previous plate (based on the one from the stop event), this would maybe do the trick.

Anyone could give me an idea on what I should do to achieve that ?